# Adding image to page after uploading it

Tags: php, html, image, dom

Ho to add an image to a page if it exist in a folder on my server?

I am building a portfolio site for my graphic design work; And I want to be able to just upload a picture to a folder on my server and have it automatically added to the page, so I don't have to physically edit the html every time I want to add a new image.

Is this possible? And if so, how? I'm a pretty fast learner so I don't really care how complicated it might be.

Comment: Maybe you can do do it with AJAX, and refresh your portfolio everytime an image is uploaded

Comment: You will want to use a database to index your images, won't you ? Otherwise if you know the image path, you can check it's existence with php function [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure that's not what he wants. Databases are cool and all that, but really, they aren't the answer to everything. Especially when the filesystem will do just fine.

Comment: Instead of asking all at once, start with the part that's creating that question with you and then ask specifically. Otherwise that broad the answer is: Yes, it works. And it's not complicated.

Comment: The title of this question is slightly misleading, as dynamically adding to the DOM would imply AJAX and that the page is being updated without a refresh - it sounds as if you just want to use PHP to generate HTML that includes all the images in a directory, correct?

Comment: @caRameL This has nothing to do with AJAX, all the OP wants to do is display an image on a page without having to rewrite HTML every time to do is.. to the OP, all you have to do is just use a a script that either picks a picture at random from a directory listing (if you just want one image to show up at a time) or.. You could use a Database to track all the files you upload and quantify as a portfolio item, and have it pull the image and other information (maybe a description for it) from the DB and have it display that way. In all it depends on what you wanna do how you wanna do it.

Comment: The other questions I would have are: what do you want the output to look like?  Links?  Images?  Any ordering?  Are thumbnails desired/required?  The question is a bit too vague to provide a good answer . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
    <?php

    $files = glob('folder/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach($files as $file) {
      echo "<img src='$file'>";
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Completely overlooked GLOB_BRACE before. +1 for that.

Comment: Sorry I was a little vague, this worked perfectly; seems so simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/pictures/');
        while($file = readdir($handle)){
            if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..'){
                echo '<img src="pictures/'.$file.'" border="0" />';
            }
        }
```

This code is really easy to understand, we first define a variable "$handle", which will contain the handle to the absolute path of the folder (I always go for absolute paths since I find them much safer)
dirname(realpath(**FILE**)) returns the absolute path to the current file (gallery.php) and then we add to the end of it /pictures/

Then, we loop through all the files in the directory, that simple if statement I used is to prevent some the function returning . or .. as file names sometimes. We then display the image in standard html

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this pseudo-code:

```
if (file_was_uploaded()) {
    update_page();
}
```

In the `file_was_uploaded` function you put your code to handle the file-upload. Return true if there was a (successful) file-upload.

In the `update_page` function you put your code to handle updating the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading the filenames in your folder and then display each image on the page:

```
<?php
$dir_path   = '/images';
$filenames = scandir($dir);
?>

<?php foreach($filenames as $filename): ?>
    <img src="<?=$filename;?>" alt="photo"/> <!-- and other HTML stuff -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```